# Time difference 1h off

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript function:

```
timeDiff = function(date, time1, time2, time3, time4) {
    var dateVmS = convertToDate(date, time1);
    var dateVmE = convertToDate(date, time2);
    var dateNmS = convertToDate(date, time3);   
    var dateNmE = convertToDate(date, time4);

    console.log(dateVmS);   
    console.log(dateVmE);
    console.log(dateNmS);
    console.log(dateNmE);

    return new Date((dateVmE.getTime() - dateVmS.getTime())
                  + (dateNmE.getTime() - dateNmS.getTime()));
}
```

These are the logs of the dates:

- Thu Apr 23 2015 08:15:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
- Thu Apr 23 2015 12:02:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
- Thu Apr 23 2015 12:37:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
- Thu Apr 23 2015 15:02:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)

When calculating the time difference manual, this is 6:12:00.

But my code returns 7:12:00. But I'm using the same way of calculating (calculating in excel says it's also 6:12, using the same `((B - A) + (D - C))`  method)

EDIT:
**The function get's called in the following way:**

`timeDiff("08:15","12:02","12:37","15:02")` and the date is like following: `23/03/2015`

then the convertToDate get's called:

```
convertToDate = function(date, time){
    var tempH = time.split(':');
    var tempDate = date.split('/');
    return new Date(tempDate[2], tempDate[1], tempDate[0], tempH[0], tempH[1], 0);
}
```

and that's it.

Comment: can you give an example that show how you use the function ( what variable you are passing)  thanks.

Comment: Updated, with some more info

Comment: I assume this has something to do with the time change on March 29th to Central Europe Daylight Time.  You are returning a new date, passing it a time but not a date, so it is using your current timezone (not CEDT).

Comment: Any suggestions  on how to fix that?

Comment: Do you see that you entered `23/03/2015` and you got Apr instead of Mar for month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your month conversion is wrong, you should put a number between 0 and 11, so you should reduce of 1 if you take it from internet. Then is strongly recommended if you use the UTC as written below.

```
 convertToDate = function (date, time) {
    var tempH = time.split(':');
    var tempDate = date.split('/');
    var newDate = new Date(Date.UTC(tempDate[2], tempDate[1] - 1, tempDate[0], tempH[0], tempH[1], 0));
    return newDate;
}

timeDiff = function (date, time1, time2, time3, time4) {

    var dateVmS = convertToDate(date, time1);
    var dateVmE = convertToDate(date, time2);
    var dateNmS = convertToDate(date, time3);
    var dateNmE = convertToDate(date, time4);

    return new Date((dateVmE.getTime() - dateVmS.getTime()) + (dateNmE.getTime() - dateNmS.getTime()));
}
```

As @Tom wrote on his comment, in javaScript you are using the [CEST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Summer_Time) instead in your excel you're using [CET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time), that's why the difference of one hour.

To avoid that you should use the Universal Time.

Reference:

[**MDN- Date.UTC()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

Comment: `(x + offset) - (y + offset) = z` and that's the same `z` you'd get with `x - y = z`

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I get my dates via Jquery from a page, so I need to convert the existing code (that you can see in first post). If you would have some spare time ... :D

Comment: @Shomz, you're definitely right, his error is mostly due to the wrong month conversion, anw the UTC is strongly recommended

Comment: @FrancescoE. the `.getUTCTime();` doesn't work I get: `undefined is not a function`

Comment: @Kiwi: you're right, now it should work, you have to adapt it to your logic.

Comment: Still one Hour off :/